# How do I hide/remove a views menu tab from some pages?

Tags: views

I created a page view with Page Settings for the path being equal to:
node/%/content/recentnews

I also set the Page Settings menu to have a menu tab.

How does that system decide what pages will display the menu tab?

I have one page where the menu tab is displayed, but I don't want it to be shown on that page. Is there some way to remove/hide it?

Thanks,
Greg

Comment: Please accept some answers. Otherwise people will feel like you do not appreciate answers and stop answering your questions.

Answer (score 1):

There are two factors to consider when determining whether the tab is displayed:

- The parent menu item
- The result of the access callback

You probably cannot do much about the parent menu item, because this points to the generic `node/%node`.

You can, however, influence the result of the access callback by configuring how to validate the argument. This allows you for example to display the tab only for nodes of a certain content type. Of course you will have to configure the view to hide the view/display 404 if the argument does not validate.

A fancier validation would be possible if the validation configuration dialog would allow you to enter PHP code. I don't know if this is the case, so you might have to look for a different solution.